# Analysis: Proving Density

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This question asks me to prove that the definition of dense could be given as

"A Set *E* of real numbers is said to be *dense* if every interval (a,b) contains infinitely many points of *E*" as opposed to my given definition where every interval (a,b) contains a point in *E*.

I thought to begin this proof, I can assume that *E* is dense given my given density definition is true. Thus, there exists some c that is an element of *E* and in the interval (a,b). Since *E* is dense, there must be a point in *E* and the interval (a,c). This can continue on and on. Can someone help me formalize this proof or give suggestions on a better way to prove it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are in the correct track!

Lets start as you said, taking an interval $(a,b)$ and our set $E$.

Since $E$ is dense (with your definition), there exist $c_1 \in (a,b) \cap E$ then $(a,c_1) \subset (a,b)$. Again, since $E$ is dense, there exist $c_2 \in (a,c_1)\cap E$. Inductively, you can find, for every $n\in \Bbb{N}$ a $c_n \in (a,c_{n-1})\cap E$ and of course, $(a,c_{n-1}) \subset (a,b)$. Therefore the set $\{c_n:n \in \Bbb{N}\} \subset (a,b)\cap E$